# Did Iranians fight in the Battle of Karabala? (As Imam Hussein's soldiers)?

Tags: history, hussain, karbala

As it is considered as a famous Islamic epic event (especially for Shias), in those days of Mohram, Imam Hussein (a.s.) and his soldiers martyred in the battle of Karbala… and the tenth day of Moharam is called Ashura…
see this [tadabbor.org](http://www.tadabbor.org/?page=article&AID=742) article.

I was wondering if there was any Iranian person (s) during that even.  (I mean as a soldier(s) of Imam Hussein)?

*Note: please, present your claim by reference.*

Comment: Iranian is an anachronism in this context. Kufa and Baghdad (Iraq) were  part of the Sassanid (Persian) empire. There was no Iran or Iraq in the Ummayad period. Do you mean any person from Isfahan or Khurasan?

Comment: You mentioned intereresting issue. To the best of my knowledge, there must be Arab in Iraq even in that time instead of Fars(Iranians). Perhaps I can ask for non-Arabs were related to Iran. I appreciate you smartness for the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here's a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_casualties_in_Husayn's_army_at_the_Battle_of_Karbala) of casualties in Husayn's army at the battle.

As far as i can see there are a few man identified to be Persians or who have been settled down in Kufa etc. among them: Nasr ibn Naizar (May Allah be pleased with him) who's the only one listed as a Persian or (as a freed slave) coming from Persia in that list.

From Kufa as it seems -I'm just trying to analyze the list- you'll find much more:

Hani ibn Orwah, the two brothers Sa'd and Abdul Hatoof Ansari, Zuhayr ibn al-Qayn al-Bajali (one of the commanders on the site of Imam al-Husayn (may Allah be pleased with him)), Jahib ibn Hajjaj at-Taymi, Habib Ibn Amir e Taimi, **Sayeed** Ibn Abdullah Hanafi, the two cousins Saif Ibn Hars al Jabiri and Malik, Zarghamah Ibn Malik e Taghlabi, Aabis ibn Abi Shabeeb al-Shakiri, Abdullah Ibn Bushr Khashami, Abdul Rahman and Abdullah sons of Orawah Ibn Harraq al Ghaffari, Omer Ibn Zabiah Az Zabiyee and Nafi ibn Hilal al-Jamali.

But those names are just what i conclude from the list above so maybe i added or forgot some by mistake. Maybe some history books could give you more help as these people might not necessary be Persian while other's in the list could be so as Kufa was part of the Sassanid empire as @Shoaib stated but this don't necessary mean that all people from there who participated in that Battle were Persian!

According to **Shi'a** references one can add the following Names:
Aslam ibn 'Amr اَسلَم بن عَمرو (in the above list the freed slave Aslam?), Rafi' ibn Abdullah  (in tha above list the freed slave Rafe?) رافع بن عبدالله, Zaher (Zahir) ibn 'Amr (al) Kindy زاهر بن عمرو کندی (in the above list Zavir ibn Amro al Kandi?), Fayruzan and Nassr ibn Abi Nouzayr (=Nasr ibn Naizar?) فیروزان و نصر بن أبی نیزر. [As quoted in the comment and [link](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa32475)  from @Shia_Sunni_________UNITY]

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Oh dear mate, what you have presented as a list of the names... looks helpful to some extent.  God bless you.

Comment: Kufans are Iraqi if you have to retrofit current demarcations

Comment: @Shoaib indeed that's the problem, as i don't really know which places where parts of persia at the time for example i found someone from Hamadan etc. so maybe seyyid-ali can find what he wants in the list!

Comment: @Medi, firstly I appreciate your profitable response. Secondly would you please add the following list of names (which is based on Shia view too) in order to make your answer more complete (as both Sunni-Shia view), in order to make it worthy to be chosen as the favorite answer. (As you wish, mate) JazakAllah-Khaira .  /  .    .    .

اَسلَم بن عَمرو، رافع بن عبدالله، زاهر بن عمرو کندی، فیروزان و نصر بن أبی نیزر.
.    .     .
(Source: http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa32475)